# Test that an expected Exception was thrown in Io

Tags: iolanguage

Is there an idiomatic way, that does not duplicate code and checks that an exception was thrown in Io when unit-testing?

So far:

```
threw := false
e := try(_method that should throw_)
e catch(Exception, threw = true)
if(threw not, fail("Should have thrown an Exception, but did not!"))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in expectation for that in Io's UnitTest. However, building a custom expectation isn't difficult at all, you could write this submit a pull request and use it just dandy.

Alternatively, if you're not hung up on using UnitTest, you can use my fork of [iospec2](https://github.com/jeremytregunna/iospec) which has this expectation (and others) built in. My fork was done for my IoSpec project, so it's embedded with IoSpec. You'd be interested in the top-level `iospec` script and everything inside `lib`.